int i; Is it a declaration or a definition?
I want to know whether the statement int i; is a declaration or a definition.
It seems that if a variable is not initialized outside the function, it is declared, but inside the function it must be defined. Is this really the case?
If I write this statement multiple times outside the function, it compiles.
If I write multiple statements inside the function, it does not compile.

depends on your definition of declaration

@yvs2014 In this contex, the definition in the C standard is what matters. It would be utterly strange if OP had a different definition and asked people on SO to categorize int i; according to that, unknown, definition.

I think this is explained in most C programming language book.

Inside a function, int i; is a definition.
Outside a function, int i; is a tentative definition. In spite of its name, a tentative definition is not an actual definition, the same way a prospective employee on a job interview is not yet an employee. This complication is largely due to the history of how C developed. We can consider three forms:

extern int i; is a plain declaration.
int i; is a declaration that is a tentative definition.
int i = value; is a definition.


If I write this statement multiple times outside the function, it compiles.

Yes, this shows that int i; outside a function is a declaration that is not a definition, as discussed below.
Definitions like int i = value; cannot be repeated because each one would create a new object, and then you would have multiple objects named i in the same scope, which is not defined by the C standard.
Declarations like extern int i; can be repeated because they just describe what i means without creating an object.
int i; outside a function can be repeated because it is just a declaration, not an actual definition.
Given int i;, you can also have one definition, such as int i = 3;. However, if a translation unit (a source file being compiled, with all the files it includes) contains a tentative definition but not actual definition, a definition will be created for it, as if the translation unit ended with int i = 0;. So a program that contains just int i; will have an object named i.

If I write multiple statements inside the function, it does not compile.

Yes, this shows int i; inside a function is a definition.
If we were designing a new programming language from scratch with foresight, we might avoid this irregularity and specify a grammar that clearly distinguished non-definition declarations from definitions just be their form instead of their context. However, C developed by exploration and contributions by multiple people, so parts of it are grown organically rather than designed.
